# Connecting Pi3 ModelB with a Sony PS3 DualShock controller

Tags: pi-3, joystick

I bought the following model of Raspberry Pi3 from Amazon.

```
RASPBERRYPI3-MODB-1GB
```

which claims to support: `Bluetooth 4.1, Bluetooth Low Energy`

And I also got a Sony DualShock PS3 controller with `Model No: CECHZC2U`

I am trying to connect them using the sixaxis library based on the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth libbluetooth3 libusb-dev
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
Reboot after changing the user group.
```

Plug in the PS3 with USB cable. Hit center PS logo button. Get and build the command line pairing tool. Run it:

```
wget http://www.pabr.org/sixlinux/sixpair.c
gcc -o sixpair sixpair.c -lusb
sudo ./sixpair
```

Use bluetoothctl to pair

```
bluetoothctl
agent on
devices
trust <MAC ADDRESS>
default-agent
quit
```

Unplug USB cable. Hit center PS logo button.

To test that the Bluetooth PS3 remote is working, verify that /dev/input/js0 exists.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find the /dev/input/js0 at all. Has anyone successfully connected a Pi3-ModelB to a PS3 controller? Thanks!